# What's the probability of choosing a given index within some matrix?

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, euclidean-geometry

Let's say I have an 11×11 matrix, and one of the values is determined to be the 'best' (by some set of experiments). That value exists in my current example at coordinates (5,9). But what if I had some prediction model that predicted the position was at (6,10) ?

[image: Illustration]

1. What are the chances of predicting an index that is equal to the 'correct' index? Is that just 1/121 = 0.00826 ?
2. Can I find out the chances of predicting an index 'close' to the true index? Maybe using a Euclidean distance threshold?

...for example: Can I calculate the probability of predicting an index that falls within Euclidean distance of 2 from the correct index?

Comment: Is your prediction method simply choosing a point a random?  Or do you try to apply some skill to the information you have?  If all you have is your threshold, then it may be worth not predicting in the corners

Comment: This all depends very much on what your "prediction model" is and how you're using probabilities to model randomness and/or uncertainty. Once you've decided on those things, you can certainly try calculating the probabilities you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If all that is known is this little, the probability is $\frac{1}{121}$.

However, you should look for more information, whatever it be, to improve your the chances of hitting the right now.